# Can you change the memory address of a C non-pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, data-structures

I have been implementing some C data structures in order to fully understand them.

This is my definition of a string linked list:

```
typedef struct str_linked_list {

   const char*                 data;
   struct str_linked_list*     next;

} str_linked_list;
```

And this is the implementation of a function that deletes the nth element of the list:

```
void str_remove_at(str_linked_list* list, int index) {
    // Invalid index case
    if (index < 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Error, array index < 0\n");
        return;

    } 

    str_linked_list* to_delete; // Always gonna need this
    // Delete head case
    if ( index == 0 ) {

        to_delete = list;
        // If this node is not the last one save the reference to the remaining ones
        if ( to_delete->next != NULL )
            list = list->next;

        //free(to_delete);
        return;

    }
    // General case
    int i = 0;

    str_linked_list* buf = list;

    for (i = 0; i != index-1; i++) {

        if (buf->next != NULL){

            buf = buf->next;

        } else {

            fprintf(stderr, "The list is not that long, aborting operation");
            return;

        }

    }

    to_delete = buf->next;

    if ( to_delete->next != NULL )
        buf->next = to_delete->next;

    free(to_delete);

}
```

So far it works well, but I believe the way I call it makes impossible to delete the head, and that is why the free(head) is commented. I have tested this code using the following code:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main() {

    str_linked_list l;
    l.data = "Hello, World";
    l.next = NULL;

    str_remove_at(&l, 1); 


    str_print(&l);

    printf("\n\n");

    str_remove_at(&l, 0);
    str_print(&l);

    return 0;
}
```

I kind of figure out that not initializing the list as a pointer makes it difficult to change the memory address in which that variable is stored in. Do I have to re-code the lib in order to initialize the lists as pointer or is there a way in which I could assign the memory position of the variable to another address?

Summarizing everything, can I change the value of "i" like this?

```
#include "stdlib.h"

void change_value(int* i) {
   int* new_alloc = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *new_alloc = 1;
    i = new_alloc;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    change_value(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you summarize your question further? Are you asking something like, can you change the address of `int i`, for example?

Comment: Be consistent with your allocation methods and no such problem will arise.

Comment: That exactly, gonna change it, thanks.

Comment: Not related to your actual question, it seems that `if ( to_delete->next != NULL )` is wrong, and the correct behaviour would be achieved by assigning `buf->next = to_delete->next` unconditionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few alternatives for solving the case of deleting the head of the list:

A) Pass the list as `**list`, allowing you to assign the head from within the function, i.e., call as `str_remove_at(&list, i)` and use `*list` instead of `list` inside the function.

B) Return the head of the list from the function, in which case the caller should do `list = str_remove_at(list, i)`.

C) Require your list to have a "sentinel" element at the head, which is never removed, and the actual list begins at `head->next`. This "wastes" one list node, but may simplify other operations as well when the actual first element is no longer a special case. (The benefits of this are increased if you have a doubly-linked list.)

D) Instead of passing a pointer to a node in the list, have a separate `str_list_node` and `str_linked_list`, with the `str_list_node` being your current `struct` with `data` and `next`, and `str_linked_list` having `str_list_node *head`. Then when you pass `str_linked_list *list` you can change `list->head` without having to change `list` itself. (This solution may be expanded to have other benefits, like being able to store `str_list_node *tail` for O(1) appending.)